# Uncheck script generated checkboxes with similar ids but different names

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox

Here's example code:

```
<form method="post" action="actions.php">
<div id="container">
<input type="checkbox" name="action1" id="a1-100" value="100"> Action 1 on 100
<input type="checkbox" name="action2" id="a2-100" value="100"> Action 2 on 100

<br><br><br><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="action1" id="a1-200" value="200"> Action 1 on 200
<input type="checkbox" name="action2" id="a2-200" value="200"> Action 2 on 200
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Perform Actions">
```

Consider this example a list of PHP-generated checkboxes as form elements - where the PHP only generated 2 checkboxes for 100 and 2 checkboxes for 200.

I only want either Action 1 or Action 2 for each unique value. So if, for value 100, Action 1 is checked, I want Action 2 for value 100 to be unchecked, without affecting anything in other values.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with radio buttons:

```
<form method="post" action="actions.php">
<div id="container">
<input type="radio" name="action-for-100" id="a1-100" value="100"> Action 1 on 100
<input type="radio" name="action-for-100" id="a2-100" value="100"> Action 2 on 100

<br><br><br><br>

<input type="radio" name="action-for-200" id="a1-200" value="200"> Action 1 on 200
<input type="radio" name="action-for-200" id="a2-200" value="200"> Action 2 on 200
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Perform Actions">
```

Note that I've changed the `name` attribute so it groups together the radio buttons that should be mutually-exclusive (e.g., `action-for-100` rather than `action1` and `action2`).

If you have **absolutely no choice** but to use the existing HTML, then you can use an attribute selector:

```
$("#container input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#container input[type=checkbox][value=" + this.value + "]")
            .not(this)
            .prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

That will make sure all other checkboxes within the container that have the same `value` are unchecked when "this" one is checked. It doesn't do anything if you uncheck one.

Comment: @t-j-crowder I can see why using radio buttons would be an easy fix. I wanted to create an array of values for action 1 and action 2 - through the checkboxes - whereby I could use PHP to execute those actions by looping through them. Thank you very much for your answer. I think I'll start off by trying the jquery solution you provided and, if I'm still unsatisfied, I'll switch to radio inputs.